# Can't sign ClickOnce manifest on a new computer

Tags: c#, certificate, clickonce

I am trying to publish a ClickOnce project that was signed with a certificate I created a few years ago following the approach in [this post](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/maximelamure/archive/2007/01/24/create-your-own-pfx-file-for-clickonce.aspx).
The certificate doesn't expire until 2039.

Complete error reads

> Error 5   An error occurred while signing: **Failed to sign
>   bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe**. SignTool Error: **The signer's
>   certificate is not valid for signing**. SignTool Error: **An error
>   occurred while attempting to sign: bin\Release\app.publish\setup.exe**

This is the first time trying to publish from a new desktop computer.  I still have access to my old computer and when I look at the certificate via certmgr.msc and view the "Certificate Path" tab on *my new computer* I see the message "*This certificate has an invalid digital signature.*" while *my old computer* simply says "*This certificate is OK*".

I see a number of threads on related topics, but have yet to find a solution that works here short of using a completely new certificate which will prevent users from being able to get updates unless they re-install.  I can still publish from the old computer but will not have access to it indefinitely.

Comment: You will need to find out what Certificate Authority issued your certificate and trust it on the new machine.

Comment: Most likely, it was self signed, so you need to import it to the Certificate Authorities store.

Comment: It is self signed, however I have already imported it. It is in the Certificate Authorities store that I see the "This certificate has an invalid digital signature" text.  Have I done something wrong during the import perhaps?